# Incompatible value type Object

Tags: apex, code

I am getting the following error while adding elements to a map.

Error:-

Incompatible value type Object

Code:-

```
public class CR_Report{

public void Completed_CR_Report(){

    //Compare old zip  on account with the new zip.. if it is different insert the record into
    // CR_Audit_Move__c


 List<Change_Request_MDV__c> CRCompletedList=new List<Change_Request_MDV__c>([Select Account__c,Name,Status__C,Reason__c,
                                                                            New_Territory__c,Zip_MDVN__c, State_MDVN__c,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate
                                                                            from Change_Request_MDV__c
                                                                            where Status__C='On Hold'
                                                                            and Reason__c in ('Completed')
                                                                            and LastModifiedDate=Today]);

Map<String,String> AccCRMap=new Map<String,String>(); 

 for(Change_Request_MDV__c c: CRCompletedList){

    AccCRMap.put(c.Account__c,c.Id);


 }

 List<Account> AccCRList=new List<Account>([Select Id from Account
                                           where ID IN:AccCrMap.keyset()]);

 Map<String,String> OldAccMap=new Map<String,String>();

 Map<String,String> NewAccMap=new Map<String,String>();

 List<AccountHistory> AccHistoryList=new List<AccountHistory>([Select AccountId,oldvalue,newvalue from 
                                                               AccountHistory
                                                               where field='Territory_vod__c'
                                                               and AccountId IN:AccCrMap.keyset()]);

    for(AccountHistory ah:AccHistoryList){

        oldAccMap.put(ah.AccountId,ah.oldvalue);  /// >>>>>>>>Error Line<<<<

        //NewAccMap.put(ah.AccountId,ah.newvalue);


    }                                                              






}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your map is going to use an ID as the key, you should use the type  to be more accurate. I believe your issue is being caused becase the oldvalue field can hold a variety of datatypes, based on the field, so it is coming in as an object.

So, you can either, make your `map<ID,object>` (remember you will need to cast the object value back to a string) or leave it as a string, and cast the data getting added

```
oldAccMap.put(ah.AccountId,String.valueOf(ah.oldvalue));
```